# SQL Select row between two conditional rows

Tags: sql

```
id  vehicle   speed
1   ABC-12     1.2
2   ABC-34     7.3
3   ABC-56     6.3
4   ABC-78     0
5   ABC-90     5.1
6   ABC-91     0
7   ABC-92     5.1
8   ABC-93     0
9   ABC-94     0
```

I have a table with structure like this, I want to *`select all vehicles`* whose **speed = 0** but vehicle *`before that && after that`* must have **speed > 0**

Like in this above example answer should be

```
id  vehicle   speed
4   ABC-78     0
6   ABC-91     0
```

I am not sure it's possible or not

Comment: Does "before" and "after" is defined as "while ordered by `id`"? Does `id` values may have gaps? Define one DBMS and specify its version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might help

```
WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT id, vehicle, speed, lead(speed) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS ld, lag(speed) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS lg
    from yourTable
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE speed = 0 AND ld > 0 AND lg > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.*
from table_name a, table_name b,table_name c
where a.speed = 0 and b.id = a.id - 1 and b.speed > 0 and c.id = a.id + 1 and c.speed > 0;
```

Comment: Be aware that it became unfashionable to write queries this way ca. 1992

Answer (score 0):

As a note, you can do this with just one window function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when speed > 0 then 1 else 0 end) over
                 (order by id
                  rows between 1 preceding and 1 following
                 )
                ) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where speed = 0 and cnt = 2;
```